# While animating parent view child view also animates

Tags: android, animation, view, scale

I have a relative layout(parent view) and a button (child view) inside this relative layout.i am applying scale animation on parent view in order to get slide down and slide up animation.but when scale animation is applied to parent view its child view also scales.is there any why to stop child from animation 
here is my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout 


    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80px"
    android:id="@+id/txt_help_gest"
    android:background="#111111"

    >

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="toggle_contents1"
    android:text="title" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

my scale animation code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"

    android:toYScale="0.5" />
```

scale to 0.5 means i want my view to scale to half from orignal size but its child is also becoming to half

my java code

```
public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v) {

    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slidedown);


a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b.clearAnimation();
        }
    });

    if (a != null) {

        a.reset();

        if (v != null) {

            v.clearAnimation();

            v.startAnimation(a);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you parent view to get slide up or down you have to use **[translate animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element)** instead of scale. Try this (your child view will have original size stil):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="50%" />
```

Comment: by using translate animation my view does not slide down instead it opens with a jerk

Comment: actually i want to get a drop down effect which cant be achieved through translate animation